# Getting Client local timezone in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm creating a form to be filled and submitted by users using VB.net. This form depends on the client's local timezone and i want this timezone to change with daylight savings.

I tried looking for solutions online and all were in JavaScript. Is there a way to find the client local timezone using VB.NET?

It worked using javascript. The code is:

```
function GetDate() {
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
console.log(offset);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these:

```
System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset()
System.TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(Now)
```

or this:

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset
```